# A function reaching local minimum everywhere

Tags: real-analysis

If I have a function $f$ on $R$ reaching local minimum everywhere, is the set of its values, i.e. $\{y|f(x) = y, x \in R\}$ countable?

It seems that its shape could be complicated, such as the characteristic function $\chi$ of the Cantor set. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What if $R$ is a non connected set and/or $f$ isn't continuous?

Comment: @RossMillikan Only if $f$ is continuous; the characteristic function of an open set has a local minimum everywhere.

Comment: @RossMillikan Doesn't the characteristic function of an open set $U$ have a local minimum at every point of $\mathbb R$ though? Any $x\in U$ is a local minimum, since $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and any $y\not\in U$ is a local minimum since it is a global minimum.

Comment: So in general this statement is false because of the constant functions, but you can try to add some hypothesis to improve the discussion...

Comment: @LeoMito Here by 'countable' I mean finite or countably infinite...